# How I can get the value from ListItem to TextField when after finished drag and drop?

Tags: reactjs

Now I am trying to drag and drop in my React. After I do drag and drop from `ListItem`, I'd like to see the result in `TextField`. How I can do that?

```js
<List className="md-cell md-paper md-paper--1 md-cell--12"   >
    <ListItem primaryText={text.text1} onDragStart = {(event) => this.onDragStart(event, text)} draggable/>
</List>

<TextField id='floating-center-title' label="Content" defaultValue={content}
    rows={9} className="md-cell--bottom --content" onChange={this.handleChange}
    onDragOver={(event)=>this.onDragOver(event)} 
    onDrop={(event)=>this.onDrop(event, "Done")}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the value in state of your component.
You can use state in class component or hooks in functional component.